# Win 10: How can I make an window be always on top but non-interactive (clicks go through)?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player, autohotkey

I'm trying to set up a small window in my screen that is always on top but at the same time "ghosted" (not sure about the term), meaning I can't interact or activate it and any mouse click would go through it.

To be more specific I want VLC playing videos in a small window on top of a videogame, without it preventing me from interacting in that area of the screen.

So far I have been trying WinWarden (an AHK script) and managed to set the position and the size of the window but I can't figure out how to make the window non-interactable (In theory WinWarden has the capacity to do that but I haven't managed to make it work).

Any idea on how to do this or where to start?

Comment: [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) provides this ability

Comment: Great to know about this, I just downloaded and seems super complete!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs something similar, I managed to make it by adding a couple lines of code to the WinWarden script from the information in [this](https://jacks-autohotkey-blog.com/2016/07/22/the-winset-exstyle-command-for-mouse-click-transparent-windows-intermediate-autohotkey-tip/) post

Comment: This answer will be useless if the linked site disappears or the link breaks. Please include the "couple lines of code" here. Make your answer standalone.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> makes the current window *Always On Top*, *Click-through*, and *Transparent*.

- You can set a custom transparency value like `Montage(128)`, but I've found `187` seems to be a good compromise on light and dark backgrounds:

```ini
Montage(trans := 187){
  WinSet AlwaysOnTop, OFF, A            ; Tricky! A Style value cannot be negative.
  WinGet ExStyle, ExStyle, A            ; If it would be negative, it is not applied.
  WinSet ExStyle, -0x80020, A           ; Therefore, if the style value has not changed,
  WinGet Normal, ExStyle, A             ; then it never had a Style to begin with.

  if (ExStyle = Normal){
    WinSet AlwaysOnTop, On, A           ; Apply styles.
    WinSet ExStyle, +0x80020, A
    WinSet Transparent, % trans, A
  }
  return
}
```

- Better comments and refactor bitwise operations:

  ```ini
  #!Space:: Montage()

  Montage(trans := 187){
    WinExist("A")                         ; Last Found Window
    WinGet ExStyle, ExStyle               ; Store the Extended Styles in the variable ExStyle.

    if (ExStyle & 0x80028) == 0x80028 {   ; WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_TOPMOST
      WinSet AlwaysOnTop, Off             ; Uses SetWindowPos instead of SetWindowLong.
      WinSet ExStyle, -0x80028            ; Remove clickthough and transparency.
    } else {
      WinSet AlwaysOnTop, On              ; Although WS_EX_TOPMOST (0x8) is an ExStyle, it requires SetWindowPos.
      WinSet ExStyle, +0x80028            ; Add clickthough and transparency.
      WinSet Transparent, % trans         ; Set window transparency value.
    }
  }
  ```
- Faster, improved version, fixing race conditions:

  ```ini
  Montage(trans := 187){
    WinExist("A")                         ; Last Found Window
    WinSet AlwaysOnTop, OFF               ; Tricky! A Style value cannot be negative.
    WinGet ExStyle, ExStyle               ; If it would be negative, it is not applied.
    WinSet ExStyle, -0x80020              ; Therefore, if the style value has not changed,
    WinGet Normal, ExStyle                ; then it never had a Style to begin with.

    if (ExStyle = Normal){
      WinSet AlwaysOnTop, On              ; Apply styles.
      WinSet ExStyle, +0x80020
      WinSet Transparent, % trans
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment; this is in response to the conversation [here](https://superuser.com/a/1614234/1905752) about the reproducibility of the given solution. I haven't tested Edison Hua's solution, but in case people already have WinWarden installed and would rather integrate a solution with that, here's what I did.

### Short Answer

**tl;dr this diff will enable mouse click-through when transparency is enabled (<100%), and disable it when transparency is set to Off** (apply this patch to `WinWarden.ahk`; you have to run the .AHK file or re-compile the .EXE after):

```
1516a1517,1518
> {
>    WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, ahk_id %actwinid%
1517a1520,1524
> }
> Else
> {
>    WinSet, ExStyle, +0x80020, ahk_id %actwinid%
> }
```

---

### Long Answer

The site [in the original comment](https://superuser.com/a/1614234/1905752) is down. Well, the link is; the actual website is now `jacksautohotkeyblog.workpress.com` and not `jacks-autohotkey-blog.com`, and the excerpt that the answerer was referring to was likely [here](https://jacksautohotkeyblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/the-winset-exstyle-command-for-mouse-click-transparent-windows-intermediate-autohotkey-tip/) (specifically [here](https://jacksautohotkeyblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/the-winset-exstyle-command-for-mouse-click-transparent-windows-intermediate-autohotkey-tip/#:%7E:text=Toggling%20Mouse%2DClick%20Transparency%20On%20and%20Off); ([Archive.today](https://archive.ph/Tkd9G), [Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20240329003732/https://jacksautohotkeyblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/the-winset-exstyle-command-for-mouse-click-transparent-windows-intermediate-autohotkey-tip/))):

> Last time I referenced a script I found in the old AutoHotkey forum for making a window always-on-top or transparent. In that same script you’ll find Hotkeys for changing any window to mouse-click transparent and back again. The following modified version of those Hotkeys include one for turning mouse-click transparency on and one for turning it off:

```
^!x::       ; Make mouse-click transparent
  WinGet, currentWindow, ID, A
  WinSet, ExStyle, +0x80020, ahk_id %currentWindow%
Return
```

```
^!z::       ; Undo mouse-click transparent
  WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, ahk_id %currentWindow%
Return
```

The WinWarden program is a giant AHK script, so edits to the .AHK file will not be reflected in the .EXE as it was self-compiled. The modification I did for my personal use is to the following part of the code (now dated back to 2005):

```
SETTRANSPACT:
WinSet,Transparent,%atransparency%,ahk_id %actwinid%
If atransparency=255
   WinSet,Transparent,Off,ahk_id %actwinid%
Return
```

which is called by the following subroutine:

```
TRANSPARENCY:
Gosub,CHECKACTIVE
If activematch=N
{
   Gosub,GETWINDATA
   atransparency:=Round(((11-transpnum)*25.6)-1)
   Gosub,SETTRANSPACT
}
Gosub,REACTIVATE
Return
```

Essentially, the transparency menu kind of acts like a jump table:

```
TRANSPMENU:
transpnum:=A_ThisMenuItemPos
Gosub,TRANSPARENCY
Return
```

`A_ThisMenuItemPos` is the position index of the menu (yes lol). This means the calculation `Round(((11-transpnum)*25.6)-1)` is actually projecting the index (Off=1, 10%=2, 20%=3, ... 90%=10) to a value between 25 and 255 using some clever math.

Looking at the earlier code snippet:

```
If atransparency=255
   WinSet,Transparent,Off,ahk_id %actwinid%
Return
```

If the index is 1 (aka `Off`), the value is 255. If the value is 255, the sentinel value of `Off` is sent to the underlying API, which turns transparency off. Otherwise, the transparency is applied.

Upon applying my diff, the code becomes:

```
SETTRANSPACT:
WinSet,Transparent,%atransparency%,ahk_id %actwinid%
If atransparency=255
{
   WinSet, ExStyle, -0x20, ahk_id %actwinid%
   WinSet,Transparent,Off,ahk_id %actwinid%
}
Else
{
   WinSet, ExStyle, +0x80020, ahk_id %actwinid%
}
Return
```

Which just adds the two `WinSet, ExStyle` lines (and braces, because the Java dev in me thinks the transition to AHK2 couldn't have come sooner) so that mouse-click-through is enabled when transparency is not 100% (aka not 255), and disabled when you click `Off` (and it is 255).

This is somewhat hacky, but in the short time that I've tested it, it works. One think to note is that you will have to ALT-TAB to the window if you want to change it (as, well, it's unclickable).

I haven't performed boundary testing per the likes of Edison Hua, so there's a chance this may collide with existing window settings, but I hope this answer at least provides a jumping off point for future discussion, as I have spent half the day trying to find what I considered from Windows to be a simple feature.